# Get Django views.py to return and execute javascript

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse

So I'm working with django and file uploads and I need a javascript function to execute after the file has been uploaded. 
I have a file upload handler in my views.py which looks like this:

```
def upload_file(request):   
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():        
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('fileAttachments'):     
            handle_uploaded_file(f)
        return HttpJavascriptResponse('parent.Response_OK();')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Failed to upload attachment.")
```

And I found a django snippet from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/341/ and I put the HttpJavascriptResponse class in my views.py code. It looks as follows:

```
class HttpJavascriptResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self,content):
       HttpResponse.__init__(self,content,mimetype="text/javascript")
```

However, when I upload a file the browser simple renders "parent.Response_OK();" on the screen instead of actually executing the javascript. And Chrome gives me the warning: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript"

Is there anyway to get views.py to execute the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this will work.

```
return HttpResponse("<script>parent.Response_OK();</script>")
```

However, you might think about returning a success (200) status code in this case, and then having some javascript in parent attach to the load event of this child, and branch based on return status code. That way you have a separation of view rendering code and view behavior code.

Comment: The code works, but I'm going to take your advice and try to have the parent's javascript trigger when the child returns the success status. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A better way is to pass the mime to the HttpResponse Object.

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.content_type.

```
    return HttpResponse("parent.Response_OK()", content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

Note - Some previous versions of Django used `mimetype` instead of `content_type`:

```
    return HttpResponse("parent.Response_OK()", mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

Comment: In recent versions of django, `mimetype` has been replaced by [`content_type`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__). However, this doesn't seem to work and the script renders as plain text rather than executing.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up here looking for a way to serve a **dynamic js file using django**.

Here is my solution :

```
return render(request, 'myscript.js', {'foo':'bar'},
                        content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me by adding the content_type

Answer (score 3):

Chase's solution worked for me, though I need to execute more javascript than I care to put in a python string:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags import staticfiles

...
    return HttpResponse("<script src='{src}'></script>".format(
        src = staticfiles.static('/path/to/something.js')))
```

Comment: This solution runs the script and then renders a plain text. Is there a solution which just runs the script and stays on the same page?

Comment: @sidpat need to do the same. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @sidpat, I used window.location.href=path/to/current/page in the js to get back the same page and run js