# Invoke a Javascript function in HTTPResponse

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964279/1526703) SO answer, I am trying to run a JS on the page in HTTPResponse

```
return HttpResponse("<script>alert('Yep, JS running.');window.location.href='/path/to/original/url'; parent.show_modal_form('" + json.dumps(my_list) + "');};</script>")
```

But the js function is defined in the page referenced above and it tries to execute the script before loading (and not after loading) the page, and hence fails to find the function. Any ideas on how to make it execute after the window.location.href has loaded the page, so that it can find the js function being called ($(document).ready won't work because JQuery is also not loaded yet. I tried window.load but that also does not work (i.e it fails to find the javascript function))

My use case is that the user performs an action in the Django Admin page, and as a result the user needs to see a modal dialog form on the same page (after executing some logic back in the view)

Comment: @amrit - thats the link I have in the question too

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18048352/1526703) SO post, any script after window.location.href is ignored and the new page (being directed to) takes over. So, it is not possible to move to another page and invoke a javascript function on that page in this way (unless a JS function is executing on page load and we pass parameters within the URL itself)